# How can fetch both using json and file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, webhooks

I am trying to upload photo message with text to discord webhook using javascript fetch api. How can I upload both my json and file?

```
var discordWebHookBody = new FormData()
discordWebHookBody.append("map", map)
discordWebHookBody.append("json", {
    "username": "Plane-notifier",
    "content": content
})
await fetch(this.config.discordWebhookUrl, {
    body: JSON.stringify(discordWebHookBody),
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
});
```

Comment: You should share the implementation which you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this json pattern(data) to send with a webhook api call to send message with photo.

```
const url = "webhook url"
const data = {
    "content": "Your Text here.",
    "embeds": [
        {
            "image": {
                "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/640px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png"
            }
        }
    ]
};
const customHeaders = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}

fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: customHeaders,
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
})
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```